# Creating managed accounts without storing any data on the backend

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, stripe-connect, stripe.js

I'm currently trying to create managed accounts entirely clientside, storing on the backend only the stripe account ID associated with each user. At first, I tried using stripe.js, but it doesn't seem to provide any API for working with managed accounts at all. Then, I tried using RESTful API directly, and made a request to create a managed account (a POST request to https://api.stripe.com/v1/accounts), using a publishable key. Response was a 403:

```
{
  "error": {
    "type": "invalid_request_error",
    "message": "This API call cannot be made with a publishable API key. Please use a secret API key. You can find a list of your API keys at https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys."
  }
}
```

But doesn't that mean that creating a managed account clientside is impossible or, at least, unsafe and not intended? Secret key is not supposed to become visible to the client at any point and in any form, is it? Is there something I don't understand, or are managed accounts to be created only serverside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stripe integrations require both a front-end and a back-end component.

You use Checkout or Stripe.js and your Publishable Key to collect a Customer's credit card information, which is then sent to Stripe. In return Stripe sends back a token that you can use to charge this card.

https://stripe.com/docs/checkout
https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js

You must use a backend, with your Secret Key, to create an account, a charge, a customer or take other actions on your account. So, yes, managed accounts are only created server-side.

If you need a minimal backend I'd suggest spinning up a small instance at AWS, Heroku, Digital Ocean, Linode, etc